# Change the string representation of a class itself

Tags: python

Let me make an example:

```
class Test:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "hi"
```

This changes the string representation of objects of type `Test`, but not of `Test` itself:

```
print(Test)
--> "<class 'Test'>"
```

Is it possible to overwrite the string representation of the class itself too?

Comment: interesting! may i ask you, why do you need this?

Comment: I play around with ctypes.Structure instances generated from parsed C headers. Would be nice to see what's inside the generated types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use meta classes:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "hi"

class Test(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

print(Test)
>>> hi
```

The `__repr__` method works on instances not on classes. However in python a class is itself an "instance" of a meta class `type`. So if you make a custom meta class with a custom `__repr__` method, all classes that are created with your meta class will use your `__repr__` method.

Some more reading on [meta classes](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/).